# Pass data from multiple checkboxes to api only when a submit button is clicked :react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Pass data from multiple check box to api only when a submit button is clicked

I have this accordion on my website. When I click on a check box, all checkbox values get stored in state, and at last when I click submit only the data is passed to the API.

The data stored is shown here:

```
const getAccordionItem = ({ key, label }) => {
    const source = key === "Custom" ? "custom" : "items";

    return (
      <div className="accordion-item" key={key}>
        <div
          className="accordion-title gradiantblur"
          onClick={() => navClose(key)}
        >
          {/* // onClick={setActiveCurrentIndex(item[0].date)}> */}
          <div>{label}</div>
          <i className="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        {state[key] ? (
          <div className="accordion-content  tableforsymtm">
            {(source !== "custom"
              ? state[source].filter(
                  (item) => item.category === label || item.category === key
                )
              : state[source]
            ).map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <span
                  key={`${key}__${item.id}__${index}`}
                  className="trforsymtm"
                >
                  <td>
                    <input
                      // className="invinsiveinput"
                      data-id={item.id}
                      type="checkbox"
                      id={item.id}
                      checked={item && item.positive}
                      onChange={(e) => handleCheckboxChange(e, source, item.id)}
                    />
                  </td>
                  <td className="tdoneline">
                    <label htmlFor={item.id}>{item.name}</label>
                  </td>
                </span>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        ) : null}
      </div>
    );
};
```

```
const handleCheckboxChange = (e, stateKey, itemId) => {
    const stateItems = state[stateKey];
    const index = stateItems.findIndex((item) => item.id === itemId);

    setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [stateKey]: [
        ...stateItems.slice(0, index),
        {
          ...stateItems[index],
          positive: e.target.checked,
        },
        ...stateItems.slice(index + 1),
      ],
    }));
};
```

Submit onbutton click

```
const chekbox = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const headers = {
    };

    const data = {
      items: [...state.items]
        .filter((item) => item.positive)
        .map((item) => ({
          date: state.today,
          symptom: item.id,
          positive: item.positive,
        })),
    };

    const custom = {
      items: [...state.custom]
        .filter((item) => item.positive)
        .map((item) => ({
          date: state.today,
          symptom: item.id,
          positive: item.positive,
        })),
    };
    console.log(custom);
    axios.post("/customer/submit-multiple/", data, {
      headers: headers,
    });
    axios
      .post("/customer/submit-custom-multiple/", custom, {
        headers: headers,
      })
      .then(() => {
        alert("was submitted");
        window.location.reload();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert("Cannot add submittedagain");
      });
};
```

Full code I have added in code sandbox.

Note updated according to Hirens answer.

https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-jone5tlds

The issue I am facing now is that if a user clicks a check box, its check value is added to state  and if the user unchecks the check box before submitting there will be 2 entry in the array

- one as checked (true)
- 2nd as unchecked (false)

So checkbox data 2 values cannot be submitted to array and passed to api

I want data to be passed something like this - I am getting 500 error

```
[
    {
        "date" : "2022-02-15",
        "id" : 6,
        "positive" : true
    },
    {
        "date" : "2022-02-15",
        "id" : 5,
        "positive" : true
    },
    {
        "date" : "2022-02-15",
        "id" :7,
        "positive" : true
    },
    {
        "date" : "2022-02-15",
        "id" : 11,
        "positive" : true
    },
    {
        "date" : "2022-02-15",
        "id" : 4,
        "positive" : true
    }
]
```

Comment: for check box you need function for this, pass id to fuction and check true and false , i dont know whats your data

Comment: positive: checkbox,
      date: date,
      symptom: id,

Comment: these are the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your problem correctly or not. But I've tried to make it submit values only on submit button click. Also, I tried to use the functional component and modified your code to make it simpler(I hope you'd understand the new functional component way if not, it's the new way to write React components).

You can check the full version here: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-tesla-qwmh7v?file=/src/App.js.

The API is still failing for some reason not sure why though, but the payload is as you wanted. and also, added some comments to help you. Let me know how it goes! Good luck!

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import moment from "moment";

import "./styles.css";
// function to get data from API, taken it out since it 
// does not depend on state as such, we can pass date a param
const getData = (date) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      // can be taken from localStorage
      Authorization: `token 67f023b5e798b8e7217bffc4b74a23b40666c589`
    }
  };
  return axios
    .get(
      `https://shebirth.herokuapp.com/customer/Symptoms-GET/?date=${date}`,
      config
    )
    .then((res) => res.data)
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error("error ocurred while fetching data", err);
      return null;
    });
};

const SYMPTOMS_CATEGORIES = [
  { key: "Head", label: "Head" },
  { key: "Pelvis", label: "Pelvis" },
  { key: "Legs", label: "Legs" },
  { key: "Other", label: "Other" },
  { key: "Abdomen", label: "Abdomen" },
  { key: "Mental", label: "Mental Health" },
  { key: "Custom", label: "User Defined" }
];

const styles = {
  trgrid: {
    display: "grid",
    gridTemplateColumns: "1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr"
  },
  module: {
    position: "relative",
    // background: "rgb(76, 0, 61) none repeat scroll 0% 0%",
    background: "#ffffff1c 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box",
    margin: "0px 30px",
    borderRadius: "10px",
    padding: "0px 0px 20px 0px",
    height: "40rem",
    overflowY: "scroll",
    scrollbarWidth: "thin",
    marginbottom: "10px"
  },
  txt: {
    textAlign: "left"
  },
  btn: {
    border: "1px solid #974cae",
    padding: "5px 30px",
    background: "#974cae",
    fontSize: "12px"
  },
  left: {
    textAlign: "left"
  },
  boxstyle: {
    background: "#ffffff1c 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box",
    marginTop: "10px"
  },
  flex: {
    background: "#ffffff1c 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box",
    marginTop: "10px",
    display: "flex"
    // justifyContent: "space-evenly",
    //background: "#971cae",
  },
  subbtn: {
    background: "linear-gradient(90deg, #3a51a7 30%, #b53899)",
    padding: "10px 30px",
    border: "none",
    borderRadius: "10px",
    color: "#fff",
    cursor: "pointer",
    margin: "10px"
  },
  // NOTE: just for demo styling purpose for separate headings a bit!!
  // use your own styles!!!
  accordionItem: {
    marginTop: "10px",
    marginBottom: "10px"
  },
  accordionHeader: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    cursor: "pointer",
    backgroundColor: "#7986cb",
    color: "#000",
    padding: "2px 4px"
  }
  // demo styles ends
};

const SymptomTracker = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    medicineOpen: true,
    medicineReady: true,
    symptomReady: false,
    items: [],
    dateState: [],
    custom: [],
    Head: false,
    Pelvis: false,
    Legs: false,
    Mental: false,
    Other: false,
    Custom: false,
    today: moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
    report: [],
    allValues: {
      others: "",
      bloodSugar: "",
      bloodPressure: ""
    }
  });

  // const closeMedicine = () => {
  //   setState((prevState) => ({
  //     ...prevState,
  //     medicineOpen: !state.medicineOpen
  //   }));
  // };

  // const addMedicine = () => {
  //   setState((prevState) => ({
  //     ...prevState,
  //     medicineReady: !state.medicineReady
  //   }));
  // };

  const addSymptom = () => {
    setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      symptomReady: !state.symptomReady
    }));
  };

  const navClose = (e) => {
    setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [e]: !prevState[e]
    }));
  };

  const onDateChange = (e) => {
    var dateSelected = e.target.value;
    var date = moment(dateSelected).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    console.log({ date });
    setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, today: date }));
  };

  const handleCheckboxChange = (e, stateKey, itemId) => {
    const stateItems = state[stateKey];
    console.table(stateItems);
    console.log({ stateKey });
    const index = stateItems.findIndex((item) => item.id === itemId);

    console.log({ item: stateItems[index] });

    setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [stateKey]: [
        ...stateItems.slice(0, index),
        {
          ...stateItems[index],
          positive: e.target.checked
        },
        ...stateItems.slice(index + 1)
      ]
    }));
  };

  const changeHandler = (e) => {
    setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      allValues: {
        ...prevState.allValues,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      }
    }));
  };

  const getAccordionItem = ({ key, label }) => {
    const source = key === "Custom" ? "custom" : "items";

    return (
      <div className="accordion-item" style={styles.accordionItem} key={key}>
        <div
          className="accordion-title gradiantblur"
          style={styles.accordionHeader}
          onClick={() => navClose(key)}
        >
          {/* // onClick={setActiveCurrentIndex(item[0].date)}> */}
          <span>{label}</span>
          <i className="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        {state[key] ? (
          <div className="accordion-content  tableforsymtm">
            {(source !== "custom"
              ? state[source].filter(
                  (item) => item.category === label || item.category === key
                )
              : state[source]
            ).map((item, index) => {
              const itemId = `${key}__${item.name}__${item.id}__${index}`;
              return (
                <span key={itemId} className="trforsymtm">
                  <td>
                    <input
                      // className="invinsiveinput"
                      data-id={item.id}
                      type="checkbox"
                      id={itemId}
                      checked={item && item.positive}
                      onChange={(e) => handleCheckboxChange(e, source, item.id)}
                    />
                  </td>
                  <td className="tdoneline">
                    <label htmlFor={itemId}>{item.name}</label>
                  </td>
                </span>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        ) : null}
      </div>
    );
  };

  // handle checked items submission
  const chekbox = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const headers = {
      // Authorization: `token ` + localStorage.getItem("token")
      Authorization: `token 67f023b5e798b8e7217bffc4b74a23b40666c589`
      // Authorization: `token 67f023b5e798b8e7217bffc4b74a23b40666c589`,
    };
    const data = [...state.items]
      // keep all items
      // .filter((item) => item.positive)
      .map((item) => ({
        date: state.today,
        symptom: item.id,
        positive: item.positive
      }));

    const custom = [...state.custom]
      // keep all items
      //.filter((item) => item.positive)
      .map((item) => ({
        date: state.today,
        symptom: item.id,
        positive: item.positive
      }));

    console.log(custom);
    // submit both requests parallelly and once both gets done
    // then only reload the page.
    Promise.all([
      axios.post(
        "https://shebirth.herokuapp.com/customer/symptoms-submit-multiple/",
        data,
        {
          headers: headers
        }
      ),
      axios.post(
        "https://shebirth.herokuapp.com/customer/submit-custom-symptom-multiple/",
        custom,
        {
          headers: headers
        }
      )
    ])
      .then(() => {
        alert("symptoms are submitted");
        window.location.reload();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert("Cannot add symptoms again");
        console.error(error);
      });
  };

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const headers = {
      // Authorization: `token ` + localStorage.getItem("token")
      Authorization: `token 67f023b5e798b8e7217bffc4b74a23b40666c589`
    };

    // prepare data object
    const data = {
      others: state.allValues.others,
      bloodSugar: state.allValues.bloodSugar,
      bloodPressure: state.allValues.bloodPressure,
      date: state.today,
      // combining custom and normal items together, can be separated if you want
      // in their each keys
      items: [...state.items, ...state.custom]
        // keep all items
        // .filter((item) => item.positive)
        .map((item) => ({
          date: state.today,
          symptom: item.id,
          positive: item.positive
        }))
    };

    axios
      .patch("customer/submit-symptoms-with-input/", data, {
        headers: headers
      })
      .then(() => {
        alert("symptom was submitted");
        window.location.reload();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert("Cannot add symptoms again");
      });
  };

  // this effect will fire once the component is mounted, and on `state.date` changes.
  React.useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const data = await getData(state.today);
      // console.log({ data });

      if (data) {
        setState((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          items: data.Symptoms,
          custom: data.customSymptom,
          allValues: data.symptomsWithIputs,
          report: data.last_week_symptom_report
        }));
      }
    })();
  }, [state.today]);

  return state.medicineOpen ? (
    <div className="symptom-container" style={styles.module}>
      <h2
        className="lightgradient"
        style={{
          borderBottom: "1px solid #fff",
          padding: "10px",
          margin: "0px",
          fontSize: "24px",
          // background: "#6f1f6d",
          borderTopLeftRadius: "10px",
          borderTopRightRadius: "10px"
        }}
      >
        Symptom Tracker
      </h2>

      <div style={styles.boxstyle}>
        <span style={{ fontSize: "16px" }}> Enter Date</span>
        <input
          type="date"
          className="calanderbutton"
          value={state.today}
          onChange={onDateChange}
        />

        {/* accordion */}
        <div className="accordion">
          {SYMPTOMS_CATEGORIES.map(getAccordionItem)}
        </div>
        <button type="Button" className="pinkbutton" onClick={chekbox}>
          submit check boxes
        </button>
        {/* form */}
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
          <div style={styles.flex}>
            <div
              className="marign-5"
              style={{
                transform: "rotate(90deg)",
                fontSize: "4rem",
                padding: "15px"
              }}
            >
              {/* <img src={img1} /> */}
              {/* <i className="fa fa-pencil"></i> */}
            </div>
            <div className="marign-5" style={{ padding: "10px" }}>
              <strong>Enter your weight</strong>
              <br />
              <br />

              <input
                className="inputofsymtum"
                style={{ float: "left" }}
                name="others"
                placeholder="Kg"
                onChange={changeHandler}
                defaultValue={state.allValues && state.allValues.others}
                type="text"
                // placeholder="Description"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div style={styles.flex}>
            <div
              className="marign-5"
              style={{ fontSize: "4rem", padding: "15px" }}
            >
              {/* <img src={img2} /> */}
              {/* <i className="fa fa-level-up"></i> */}
            </div>
            <div className="marign-5" style={{ padding: "10px" }}>
              <strong>Enter your blood sugar level</strong>
              <br />
              <br />
              <input
                className="inputofsymtum"
                style={{ float: "left" }}
                type="text"
                name="bloodSugar"
                placeholder="(mg/dL)"
                onChange={changeHandler}
                defaultValue={state.allValues && state.allValues.bloodSugar}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div style={styles.flex}>
            <div
              className="marign-5"
              style={{ fontSize: "4rem", padding: "15px" }}
            >
              {/* <img src={img3} /> */}
              {/* <i className="fa fa-area-chart"></i> */}
            </div>
            <div className="marign-5" style={{ padding: "10px" }}>
              <strong>Enter your blood pressure level</strong>
              <br />
              <br />
              <input
                className="inputofsymtum"
                style={{ float: "left" }}
                type="text"
                placeholder="(mmHg)"
                name="bloodPressure"
                onChange={changeHandler}
                defaultValue={state.allValues && state.allValues.bloodPressure}
                // onChange={changeHandler}
                // value={state.allValues.bloodPressure}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div style={styles.flex}>
            <div
              className="marign-5"
              style={{
                transform: "rotate(90deg)",
                fontSize: "4rem",
                padding: "15px"
              }}
            >
              {/* <img src={img4} /> */}
              {/* <i className="fa fa-pie-chart"></i> */}
            </div>
            <div className="marign-5" style={{ padding: "10px" }}>
              <strong>Last week report</strong>
              <br />
              <br />
              <p className="fontin12">
                Last week you have experienced &nbsp;
                {state.report.map((personData, key) => {
                  return (
                    <span key={key}>
                      {personData.count}&nbsp;times&nbsp;
                      {personData.symptom}&nbsp;,&nbsp;
                    </span>
                  );
                })}
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button type="submit" className="pinkbutton">
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
          <br />
          {/* {state.symptomReady ? <AddSymptom /> : null} */}
          <span
            onClick={addSymptom}
            // style={styles.subbtn}
            className="pinkbutton"
            style={{ cursor: "pointer", fontSize: "16px" }}
          >
            Add User Defined Symptom
          </span>
          <hr />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  ) : null;
};

export default SymptomTracker;
```

Comment: thanku for ur what u have tryed is what i want but there need to be some currection sir  the checkboxes under custum accourduion must be submitted to  `/customer/submit-custom-multiple/  ` this api

Comment: and all other checkboxes mustbe submitted to `/customer/submit-multiple` this api

Comment: `customer/submit-symptoms-with-input/ ` this api is for all the text fieled to submit `

Comment: u can use a sepeate submit button for all check box and a seperate button for text input field

Comment: so all together there will be 2 submit butttons 1 to submit all checkboxes and 1 to submit all text fields

Comment: This is something you can figure out I think. You just need to add submit buttons and take out the data which needs to be sent for each request.

Comment: i was able to seprate the data using a differnt submit buttton but there is anothere case that is " i cliked a check box so its data is stored in a state and  before submitting i unchecked the check box so in that case i have to remove the uncheked value from array right how to achive that i have added the latest code in sand box

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-jones-p5tlds

Comment: can u find a answerfor this

Comment: @ hiren i am getting 500 error when i submit pls help me

Comment: check thw codesand box i have updated it

Comment: Error 500 is for internal server errors, which means there is something going wrong on the server side. Check the backend code.

Comment: no i tryed with post man its working in postman

Comment: @ hiren i have added postman screenshot

Comment: i think issue with payload

Comment: Yes, the issue was with the payload. You just need to submit the array instead of the object with the key `items`. 
Check this sandbox, it's working fine now: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-robinson-850047

Comment: but when i uncheck a checkbox and submit it does not get upated

Comment: @ hiren i think it is passed as true for unchecking  checkbox also

Comment: Because it gets filtered with only `positive: true`, If you want to check for unchecked then you will have to remove the filter, or keep a separate list of changed checkboxes, which could get complicated. Is it fine to send the values for checkboxes that are not checked as false?

Comment: I have updated the code sandbox, Please check it. https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-robinson-850047?file=/src/App.js